# hide sub-article, but keep showing article when clicked on parent div

Tags: jquery, menu, hide, show

Question belongs to this site: http://bit.ly/jQD6dd

When the submenu item "Do you" > "Ziekenhuis" is clicked, it should appear the article with id "#ziekenhuis" on top of the article with id "#doyou". When clicked outside the article, but in the parent menu "#doyou", the item should stay open. When clicked anywhere else, the complete menu should dissapear.

With this code the subarticles won't show up, because the class ".article" is clicked.

```
$(function() {
  $(".article").click(function() {
    hideArticles();
    $(this).show();
  });

  $("#main-container").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == "main-container")
      hideArticles();
  });
});

function hideArticles() {
    $(".article").hide();

    $(".subart").hide();  
}
```

Does anybody have a clue to show up and hide the elements the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you take the 'href' attribute of the clicked link and show the article with the ID of that attribute?

```
$('a.btn').click(function(){
    var show = $(this).attr('href');
    $(show).show();
});
```

and then add a click event to the subarts

```
 $('.subart').click(function(){
      return false;
 });
```

I'm realizing that I didnt get what you really want..

Comment: Ok, i almost finished it with the next code: 

    function hideArticles() {
     $('.btn').click(function(){
        return false;
      });
     $(".article").hide();
     $(".subart").hide();  
    }

But at the first time when the page is loaded I have to click twice before the submenu shows up. After that it works normally

Comment: Finally i fixed it. The $('.btn').click(function(){
        return false;
      }); did it's work! Thanks. I did declare twice showhide, that's why it didn't work out.

Comment: adding the same event twice is almost everywhere a bad thing :)